# How to implement NPV, IRR, etc. in IronPython

Tags: ironpython, quantitative-finance

We are implementing a financial planning tool in .NET and are using IronPython for scripting. We need to evaluate **standard financial functions** such as NPV (Net Present Value), IRR (Internal Rate of Return), etc which are available directly in Excel as formulas.

I am wondering if these are also supported in IronPython through the **use of a library**. I have already searched on Google but did not come across any such libraries. If anyone has any experience with these, please let me know. Thanks for your help in advance!

-Nitesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that many numeric/math libraries for python rely on native components not currently supported in IronPython you could look at .NET libraries.

What is available in .NET itself is [Microsoft.VisualBasic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.aspx) and it's [Financial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.financial.aspx) class. It contains functions like [NPV](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.financial.npv.aspx) that seem to be similar to excel.

A rough translation of the usage sample from MSDN would look like:

```py
import clr
import System
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.VisualBasic")
from Microsoft.VisualBasic import Financial

values = System.Array[float]([ -70000.0, 22000.0, 25000.0, 28000.0, 31000.0 ])
fixedRetRate = 0.0625
(netPVal, refValues) = Financial.NPV(fixedRetRate, values)
print netPVal
```

The result of 19312.57 seems to be consistent with what Excel does. Please note that the result needs to be unpacked as a tuple (e.g. `(netPVal, refValues)`) as the values parameter is passed as a reference and therefore (in IronPython) has to be returned back as well.